# Adding an html file breaks my epub when loading with MacOS Books app

Tags: calibre

I have an minimum-working-example epub that I created with LaTeX and tex4ebook. It has two html files and I can load and read it fine with the MacOS Books app and with Android ReadEra. When I add an html file between the two files, Books can read up to the inserted file, but doesn't load the inserted file or the file after it and ReadEra skips the inserted file.

Is there a step I am missing? Here are the three files.

Here's the first page that renders fine:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head><title>Another Book</title> 
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='originator' /> 
<!--  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html  --> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
</head><body>
<div class='maketitle'>


<h2 class='titleHead'>Another Book</h2>
with a Subtitle
 <div class='author'><span class='ec-lmr-10x-x-109'>Peter Pan</span></div><br />
<div class='date'></div>   
</div>

 
</body></html>
```

Inserting the page below breaks the epub:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head><title>My Test Page</title> 
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='originator' /> 
<!--  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html  --> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
</head><body>

<div class='hello'>
<h2 class='saysomething'>My Test Page</h2>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the third page that render fine until the above page was added:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head><title>Introduction</title> 
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='originator' /> 
<!--  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html  --> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 10 --><div class='crosslinks'><p class='noindent'></p></div>   
<h2 class='likechapterHead' id='introduction'><a id='x2-1000'></a>Introduction</h2>
<!-- l. 11 --><p class='noindent'>Thanks for reading!
</p>   

   
<!-- l. 12 --><div class='crosslinks'><p class='noindent'></p></div>
 
</body></html>
```